# How to create high frequency signal?

Tags: signal, high-frequency

The question arose because I could not find a comprehensive answer, even though frequencies such as 2.4 and 5+ GHz are pretty common (bluetooth, modems, RC toys, etc.). So far, what I know is:

1. There are not a lot of ways to create oscillators that will provide at least 2.4 GHz of frequency, and even the few of them that can create high frequencies are expensive.
2. The other way is to create some relativly low-frequency signal (around 16 MHz) and then multiply it by PLL.
3. Also, I know about DDS, but my knowledge of it is really little. Does it generate a signal or synthesize other frequencies based on the reference signal? Could DDS multiply frequency or only control it below the reference-frequency signal?
   I described my point of view. Perhaps there are other ways to deal with this task,more efficient or more common?

Comment: Most transistors with Ft>10 GHz will oscillate if you put them onto SMD breakout boards and stick those into a breadboard. Just the parasitic impedances will be enough - bias for 10mA or more of collector current. Costs pretty much nothing. Single-transistor oscillators will go to tens of GHz without much trouble, it just matters that you set them up right. Look at Joe Smith’s YouTube videos about GHz oscillator challenge :)

Answer (score 2):

> There are not a lot of ways to create oscillators that will provide at least 2.4 GHz of frequency, and even the few of them that can create high frequencies are expensive.

I'd say there *are* a lot of ways, but the number of ways that are commercially and technologically feasible and fulfill the quality requirements for wireless communications are a bit more restricted, mainly because you typically really want the RF oscillator to be in an IC.

> The other way is to create some relativly low-frequency signal (around 16 MHz) and then multiply it by PLL.

A PLL still needs a high-frequency oscillator. You're confusing two things:

1. oscillating
2. making sure the oscillation from 1. is at the right frequency.

In practice, you'll never find a RF oscillator in these frequency ranges which is *not* disciplined by a reference oscillation, if that oscillator is used for metrology or communications purposes.

That stems from the fact that building very accurate high-Q resonators at some frequencies is material-physically easier than at others, so you use a frequency that you can easily produce very precisely to adjust the frequency of an oscillator that is at  roughly the target frequency.

> Also, I know about DDS, but my knowledge of it is really little. Does it generate a signal or synthesize other frequencies based on the reference signal?

Yes, both, at the same time. Imagine a DDS as someone having recorded samples of sine wave of a specific frequency onto a ring of tape, and now you jump around these numbers with a fixed jump length with a given rate, to play back a faster or slower version of that sine.

> Could DDS multiply frequency or only control it below the reference-frequency signal?

yes. But DDS is not how you produce RF.

> Perhaps there are other ways to deal with this task,more efficient or more common?

You typically use one of the many cheap RF synthesizers which include an oscillator, a (very advanced) PLL and an interface to receive a lower-frequency reference from e.g. an external quartz oscillator, or to drive a quartz itself to generate a low-frequency reference.

Comment: "A PLL still needs a high-frequency oscillator." For example to get 2.4ghz 16MHz referenc signal is too low frequency? If so, what reference frequency are usually required for such task?

Comment: You are still mixing things up. Look at the block diagram of a PLL: There's a high-frequency adjustable oscillator in there. You can't have a PLL without an oscillator whose phase you lock to some other oscillator's phase.

Comment: @AlexGenesis you can lock a 2.4 GHz VCO to a 16 MHz reference with a PLL, no problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK ah, that's what Alex was asking about!

Comment: By "meterology" do you mean metrology?

Comment: Yes, but my spell check was off a different opinion. Gotta fix that.